# How to validate request headers in Camel Rest

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger-codegen, spring-camel

I'm trying to build a get request and was wondering how to validate the incoming request whether it has the mandatory headers in the request. My code is

```
rest("/employee").id("get-Heartbeat").produces(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE)
            .get().description("The heartbeat API").outType(Employee.class)
            .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.OK.toString()).message("Employee data").endResponseMessage()
            .to("bean:EmployeeService?method=getEmployee()");
```

The Manadatory headers that I wanted to validate is header1, header2, header3.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in documentation claus refers to you can set **clientRequestValidation=true** on the **restConfiguration**

example

```
restConfiguration()
            .component("jetty")
            .host("localhost")
            .clientRequestValidation(true);

    rest("/employee").id("get-Heartbeat").produces(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE)
            .get().description("The heartbeat API").outType(Employee.class)
            .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.OK.toString()).message("Employee data").endResponseMessage()
            .param().name("header1").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("header2").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("header3").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .to("bean:EmployeeService?method=getEmployee()");
```

or you could make your own validation in the route

example

```
rest("/employee").id("get-Heartbeat").produces(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE).head()
            .get().description("The heartbeat API").outType(Employee.class)
            .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.OK.toString()).message("Employee data").endResponseMessage()
            .param().name("header1").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("header2").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("header3").type(RestParamType.header).required(true).endParam()
            .route()
                .validate(header("header1").isNotNull()) // or whatever you want to validate
                .validate(header("header2").isNotNull()) // or whatever you want to validate
                .validate(header("header3").isNotNull()) // or whatever you want to validate
            .endRest()
            .to("bean:EmployeeService?method=getEmployee()");
```

Comment: It worked for me, you saved my day :) . Now I'm able to validate the headers but the route one i.e the null check didn't work for me, even though I passed non-null header1 value, I got empty response (instead of Employee json data ) and got 200 OK status.

Comment: If you want to validate the header in the route and change the response code, you have to handle the validation exception. for this 'onException()' could be used

Answer (score 1):

You can define which parts in the Rest DSL are mandatory, and then turn on client request validation, then Camel will do this for you.

See more in the docs: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/rest-dsl.adoc

Comment: Thanks Claus for the response, I went through the link that you have shared, it talks more in high level but I couldn't find a way to validate mandatory headers in incoming request. I also referred camel rest example and camel-swagger example but none of them say about the procedure to validate headers. Can you share code for doing the same? Also is there a way where I can specify/route my openAPI yaml document to validate the request?